# SP2010: Timed email reminders for list workflow

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, email

Using Sharepoint 2010 Designer or Infopath 2010, I would like to create timed email reminders after an item is created.

My idea is:

1. If a field is empty, send an email out 3, 7, and 14 days after the item was created.
2. If the field is not empty, do not send those emails and/or cancel the previous email workflow.

Is this possible with list workflows or does it need to be developed? Unfortunately, I do not have access to VB Studio and I don't have the ability to install third-party apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is with a secondary workflow that waits 3 days and sends a reminder, waits another 4 days, sends a reminder, etc. You can have a parallel action that waits until the field has a value and then stop the workflow.

http://markeev.com/Articles/item-expiration-reminders-in-sharepoint-using-workflow.aspx

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7aa8326f-1fc4-4d2a-86d1-8651f5e4702e/task-reminder-workflow-using-sharepoint-designer?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious